# ping domain name to get ip with php

Tags: php, ping

so im probably dumb and this is probably very simple. I have a text file with around 300 domain names in it. I dont want to ping them manual so I am working on a simple little php script  to ping the domain name return the ip address and then echo them

I have the domains in a text file i can read the file and output thenames but the second i try to ping them all i get is a blank list of

dots like i said probably missing somthing so dumb but I appreciate any help

```
 <?php

 $names = file('sites.txt');
 foreach ($names as $name) {
 $testping = exec("ping  $name");
  echo '<li>' . $testping . '</li>';
 }

  ?>
```

new code****

```
 $names = file('sites.txt');
 foreach ($names as $name) {

   $ip = gethostbyname($name);



  echo '<li>' . $ip . '</li>';
  }

   ?>
```

Comment: After some simple googling...
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/get-domain-name-ip-address-php/

Comment: Be careful with that code. If the users can somehow influence the site names and it's not properly validated and checked, people could run arbitrary code on your machine.

Comment: exec() only returns the last line of output, which is probably a blank line. You need to use the second argument to capture all of the output: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can know the Domain for an IP by PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674010/how-i-can-know-the-domain-for-an-ip-by-php)

Answer (score 6):

If your end-goal is to get the ip address look into [`gethostbyname()`](http://php.net/gethostbyname):

```
$names = file('sites.txt');
 foreach ($names as $name) {
     $ip = gethostbyname($name);
     echo '<li>' . $ip. '</li>';
 }
```

```
echo $ip;
```

Comment: gethostbyname works great  but to further the dumbness if i replace the 'www.example.com' with the $name it still returns just the domain name

Comment: @BrandonBraner What's `$name`?

Comment: $name is the variable returned by my foreach loop after getting the host names out of the txt file see code above

Comment: @BrandonBraner Can you give me an example? One that returns a hostname for `gethostbyname($name)`

Comment: http://thepressgym.com/ping.php  (THE CODE FOR THIS IS UNDER NEW CODE ABOVE) thanks mike   edit...so i changed the sites so i dont give away clients site names lol but now www.facebook.com converts but google.com does not   second edit  ok it seems to only be converting the last one in the list

Answer (score 1):

gethostbyname() will return the IP address for any domain you enter.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php

Answer (score 0):

@BrandonBraner
Exactly what I wanted to do too! The reason why only the last entry in the list works is because PHP reads the lines correctly but appends a character at the end. It doesn't do this for the last line - don't ask me why. Perhaps it's the new line character.

To get round it, use substr:

```
    $names = file('mysites.txt');
foreach ($names as $name) {

   $mydomain = substr($name, 0, -1);
   $ip = gethostbyname($mydomain);

  echo '<li>' . $ip . '</li>';
  }
```

Did the trick for me. All you then need to do is to add an empty last line in the list of domains.