# Getting hostname by given IP address with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the hostname as fast as possible. Many of you PHP devs who have worked with GetHostByAddr, it works, but it takes a while to resolve. I've seen workarounds, and APIs, but none of them actually work that well. Are there any other ways to get the hostname faster than the gethostbyaddr function?

Comment: The PHP function it self isn't where the bottleneck is. It's how reverse DNS works, and can take a while to resolve. I'm not sure there's a simple solution but to ensure the DNS resolver on your server is functioning correctly and the upstream DNS servers are quick.

Comment: If it makes a difference, I'm using a shared host, and have read where it's even slower on a shared host, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gethostbyaddr() is limited by the speed of your OS dns resolver. If it's slow, change it. Two generally fast ones are 8.8.8.8 (Google) or 208.67.222.222 (OpenDNS). gethostbyaddr() on my system which uses OpenDNS is no slower than a raw dig enquiry, i.e. 10ms or so.

Comment: As noted by others though reverse DNS queries may be slower than normal DNS queries, depending where you're having to query. A client connecting from Australia for example, your resolver will have to go ask down in Oz, rather than possibly having a cached reply to send.

Answer (score 1):

I think GetHostByAddr function isn't problem. You can have some problems with your revDNS.

Read this: [How I can know the Domain for an IP by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674010/how-i-can-know-the-domain-for-an-ip-by-php)